# Mockito: Void type not throwing Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am new to jUnit and Mockito. I am totally confused regarding how the mocking of Void functions.
Here if the name is "hello", the function throws an exception.
But when I m testing it out, it's not throwing the exception...

```
Class MyService{

    void validate(MyData data){
        if(data.name.equals("hello"))
            throw new InvalidInput(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,"invalid");

        ResponseEntity<Object> response= // ...RestTemplate call;
        if(response.getStatusCodeValue()!=200) throw Exception....
    }

}
```

Testing

```
Class MyTesting{

  @Mock
  RestTemplate template;
 
  @BeforeEach
  void setup(){

    //mockitio init..
  }
  

  @Test
  void TestingMyFunc(){
     MyData data = new MyData();

     MyService service=mock(MyService.class);

     data.setName("hello");

     //mocking rest call
     when(template.postForEntity(..).then(..));

     doThrow(new InvalidInput(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,"invalid")).when(service).validate(data);     
   }
```

}

Comment: What is your unit under test? `service`?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mock the `MyService` if you are testing methods inside of that class, you should only mock the dependencies of `MyService` like `RestTemplate`

```
Class MyTesting{

 MyService service = new MyService();

 @Mock
 RestTemplate template;

 @BeforeEach
 void setup(){

     //mockitio init..
  }


 @Test
 void TestingMyFunc(){
     MyData data = new MyData();

     data.setName("hello");

     //mocking rest call
     when(template.postForEntity(..).then(..));

     service.validate(data);

  }
}
```